# VSO languages and generative grammar

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar, transformational-grammar

I'm wondering how generative grammar handles VSO languages

It seems to me that the subject splits up the verb phrase, and so you're going to have to have some sort of movement going on and a different underlying word order (likely SVO or SOV). It doesn't seem especially plausible to me that almost 10% of the world's languages have a default word order different from their underlying order, especially as this word order appears to be reasonably stable (I'd expect there to be a reasonably powerful pressure towards using the underlying word order as your default)

Is there something else going on, and there is a more direct way to accommodate languages with default VSO, or have I understood this position correctly and just judge its plausibility differently?

Comment: By "generative grammar", do you mean current Minimalism?

Comment: VSO languages are very similar typologically to SVO languages like English. Generative grammar can handle the distinction rather easily. Indeed, there's a famous article by Jim McCawley called ["English as a VSO Language"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/412279).

Comment: @user6726 any of the frameworks set out by Chomsky over the years

Comment: @jlawler again, my question isn't whether they can be handled by generative grammar, but whether I've understood correctly that doing so requires movement. My contention is that it seems implausible that having movement from the underlying structure to the surface structure as the default in transitive sentences seems like it ought to be far less common, or stable than it is. As such, I'm wondering if I've misunderstood and there is a way of handling VSO without movement

Comment: In an SVO language like English, being on one side or the other of the verb is usable in place of case (like English and Mandarin do), if that's what you mean. In SOV or VSO languages (or ones with free movement), it's more likely that there will be cases or other devices to distinguish verbal arguments. "Movement" is a metaphor that is used by derivationally-based generative systems like Generative Semantics; e.g, [Ross Constraints on movement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html). I have no idea what seems like it ought to be far less common, or stable than it is, unfortunately.

Comment: @jlawler if I understand these frameworks correctly, they all require underlying VO or OV. VSO lacks this on its surface and so would need movement from an underlying structure with either VO or OV. Having your default word order differ from your underlying structure seems like it should be uncommon and unstable. VSO is not as common as SVO or SOV, but still comprises almost 10% of the world's languages, and appears to be a reasonably stable feature, far moreso than I would expect if it indeed has a default word order different from its underlying structure

Comment: so my question is: have I misunderstood these frameworks (i.e. do they not in fact require an underlying VO or OV), or do people who subscribe to these frameworks believe that having a different default word order and underlying structure need not be as unusual or unstable as I suspect it would have to be? Because one of those two things must be the case

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "these frameworks", I'm afraid. "Underlying VO or OV" is an abbreviation of the generalization that SVO and VSO languages work differently from SOV languages. Those are, realistically, the only choices. The other three possible organizations just don't occur often, it appears. We don't know why, but there are theories. So if you're understanding that the theory starts from "underlying OV or VO", you've got it backwards. That's a secondary generalization and pretty unclear about its implications, as you point out.

Comment: @jlawler There are plenty of VSO languages with no case too, such as all the Insular Celtic languages. Several of these don’t even have subject/object distinctions in most pronouns (e.g. Irish _bhuail muid sibh_ ‘we beat you’ vs _bhuail sibh muid_ ‘you beat us’, and ambiguous relative clauses like _an té a bhuail mé_ ‘the person who beat me’ or ‘the person whom I beat’).

Comment: @Janus Of course. This is all generalities at the two-significant-letters level.

Comment: @jlawler VSO languages are not that unusual, again, almost 10% of the world's languages, making them more common than VOS which has VO intact

Comment: @jlawler by these frameworks I mean any of the generative frameworks proposed by Chomsky over the years

Comment: Generative Semantics was not proposed by Chomsky, over any years.

Comment: @jlawler where did I say anything about semantics?

Comment: @Tristan: [_Generative Semantics_](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1080733.pdf) is the name of a generative syntactic theory, not of anything you said.

Comment: @jlawler ok. In that case it is still relevant but the question is primarily aimed at Chomskyan generative frameworks (as clearly stated in my first comment)

Comment: @Tristan Is it important that the theory be blessed personally by Chomsky? There are many Chomskyan theories that come from his students (most theory construction is delegated this way).

Comment: this question came about because I am not directly involved with linguistic academia and am not primarily interested in syntax. The connections I do have happen to be people who are fairly critical of Chomsky and his camp. I am trying to ensure my impression of Chomsky and the frameworks he has produced is not unfairly influenced by my friends and that the doubts I hold or criticisms I have are coming from a genuinely informed place and, if my doubts are assuaged, even better